# How to test a method call in other method in Java Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

How to test with Mockito that some method was called in other method? In my case it's Collections.reverse(tasks) in a class below:

My class:

```
public class TaskReadService {

private final TaskRepository repository;

public TaskReadService(TaskRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public List<Task> readAllOrdered(TasksListOrder order) {
  
    var tasks = repository.readAll();       

    if (order.equals(TasksListOrder.BY_STATUS)) {

        tasks.sort(Comparator.comparing(jpaEntity -> jpaEntity.status));
    }

    if (order.equals(TasksListOrder.BY_PRIORITY)) {

        tasks.sort(Comparator.comparing(jpaEntity -> jpaEntity.priority));
    }

    Collections.reverse(tasks);

    return tasks;
}}
```

Comment: please add your test class

Comment: You do not want to test that that method is called, you want to assert that the output is correct, how the list was reversed should be irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, you're right but i still want to know how to verify that some method was called in other method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you do not need to verify a call to `Collections#reverse`. Your test code should not care about this but rather should focus, on the returned result which correctness should be asserted (i.e correct content, order, etc etc).

Now regarding your question on how to verify method calls, a simple visit to Mockito's [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.12.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification) shows usages of the `Mockito#verify` method which is precisely what you need to do method verifications.